# error when pushing new element to array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, arrays, push

I am trying to add comments from html form elements to array in angularjs. When I use javascipt push function I got an error "property of object doesn't exist". 
Can someone help me to solve this issue. Below you can find my javascript and html code:

Thank you for reading

```js
    .controller('DishDetailController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

            var dish={
                          name:'Uthapizza',
                          image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
                          category: 'mains', 
                          label:'Hot',
                          price:'4.99',
                          description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                           comments: [
                               {
                                   rating:5,
                                   comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                                   author:"John Lemon",
                                   date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                                   author:"Paul McVites",
                                   date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:3,
                                   comment:"Eat it, just eat it!",
                                   author:"Michael Jaikishan",
                                   date:"2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                                   author:"Ringo Starry",
                                   date:"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:2,
                                   comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                                   author:"25 Cent",
                                   date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               }
                               
                           ]
                    };
            
            $scope.dish = dish;
            
        }])

        .controller('DishCommentController', ['$scope', function($scope) {


            $scope.newcomment = {
                rating : "",
                comment: "",
                author: "",
                date: new Date().toISOString()
        };
            $scope.submitComment = function () {
                
                //Step 2: This is how you record the date


                $scope.dish.comments.push($scope.newcomment);
                
              
            }
        }])

;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="confusionApp">

<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
       <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- endbuild -->

   
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-content" ng-controller="DishDetailController">
            <div class="media" ng-model="dish">
                <div class="media-left media-middle">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="media-object img-thumbnail" ng-src={{dish.image}} alt="Uthapizza">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h2 class="media-heading"> {{dish.name}}
                        <span class="label label-danger">
            {{dish.label}}
        </span>
                        <span class="badge">
            {{dish.price | currency}}
        </span>
                    </h2>
                    <p>{{dish.description}}</p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>

        <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1" ng-controller="DishDetailController">
            <h4>Customer Comments</h4> Sort by:
            <input type="text" ng-model="filterText">
            <blockquote ng-repeat="commentla in dish.comments | orderBy: filterText">
                <p class="mb-0">  {{commentla.rating}} Stars </p>
                <p class="mb-0">{{commentla.comment}}</p>
                <footer class="blockquote-footer"> {{commentla.author}} {{commentla.date | date: 'mediumDate'}} </footer>
            </blockquote>
        </div>
    </div>

            <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1" ng-controller="DishCommentController">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                   Your Name: {{newcomment.author}}
                        <br>
                        Comment:  {{newcomment.comment}}
                        <br>
                        Your Rating: {{newcomment.rating}}


     <!-- <p>Task 3: Here you include the code to show the live preview of the comment</p>
      <p>The comment should be shown only when the form contains valid
      information and is not pristine</p> -->
                    </ul>
                <form class="form-horizontal" name="commentForm" ng-submit="submitComment()" novalidate>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="yname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Your Name:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="yname" aria-des                <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="1" ng-model="newcomment.rating"> 1
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="2" ng-model="newcomment.rating"> 2
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="3" ng-model="newcomment.rating"> 3
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio4" value="4" ng-model="newcomment.rating"> 4
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio5" value="5" ng-model="newcomment.rating"> 5
                        </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="commentm" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Your Comment</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="commentm" name="commentm" rows="12" ng-model="newcomment.comment"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="feedbackForm.$invalid">Submit Comment</button>
                        </div>
                      
                    </div>
                </form>

        </div>
    </div>

<!-- build:js scripts/main.js -->
    <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please try boiling it down to an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as this process often leads to a solution and when it doesn't it makes it easier to answer.

Comment: In Angular, scopes mirror the DOM hierarchy, therefore a scope can only inherit properties from its ancestor scope(s), with `rootscope` at the top level. A scope doesn't inherit from any of its descendants, or from any siblings, which is (it appears) what you are expecting to happen.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've tryed to create this as rootscope. Even in that case it doesn't push to array. I deleted second scope added function to the first scope. Whatever I have done it doesn't add new element to array.

Comment: Mmm, I'm at a loss. Don't know what else to advise :(

Comment: OMG I solved issue. The problem was one </div> which in Html which I closed before the access to second scope from the html code. So it took my three days ))))))) just one <div>

Comment: Aaaargh, annoying one! Congrats on finding it. Just wondering what might have helped - (1) a decent editor that colour-codes and dynamically highlights (eg Notepad++) or (2) inspecting the DOM structure in your browser's "dev tools". But even then, not much help if you don't know what your're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it has something to do with the scope of each controller. You are defining `dish.comments` in `DishDetailController` while your submit function is in `DishCommentController` controller.

Try taking the `submitcomment` function from `DishCommentController` controller to `DishDetailController` controller since `DishCommentController` doesn't even have $scope.dish.comments in its scope.

Edit: After you have updated the code as suggested, give it a try

```
 .controller('DishDetailController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    var $scope.dish ={
                  name:'Uthapizza',
                  image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
                  category: 'mains', 
                  label:'Hot',
                  price:'4.99',
                  description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                  comments: [
                       {
                           rating:5,
                           comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                           author:"John Lemon",
                           date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                       }
                       ...
                   ]
            };

    $scope.newcomment = {
        rating : "",
        comment: "",
        author: "",
        date: new Date().toISOString()
    };

    $scope.submitComment = function (rating , author, stars, date) {
        $scope.dish.comments.push($scope.newcomment);     
    }

}]);
```

I have removed some extra code which you can add back later when it start working.

```
<div class="row row-content" ng-controller="DishDetailController">          

        <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1">
            <h4>Customer Comments</h4> Sort by:
            <input type="text" ng-model="filterText">
            <blockquote ng-repeat="commentla in dish.comments | orderBy: filterText">
                <p class="mb-0">  {{commentla.rating}} Stars </p>
                <p class="mb-0">{{commentla.comment}}</p>
                <footer class="blockquote-footer"> {{commentla.author}} {{commentla.date | date: 'mediumDate'}} </footer>
            </blockquote>
        </div>    

    <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1">
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
           Your Name: {{newcomment.author}}
                <br>
                Comment:  {{newcomment.comment}}
                <br>
                Your Rating: {{newcomment.rating}}

            </ul>
        <form class="form-horizontal" name="commentForm" ng-submit="submitComment()" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="yname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Your Name:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="yname" aria-des                <div class="col-sm-10">
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="1" ng-model="newcomment.rating"> 1
                </label>
                ..
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="commentm" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Your Comment</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="commentm" name="commentm" rows="12" ng-model="newcomment.comment"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="feedbackForm.$invalid">Submit Comment</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for comment. I tried that too. But what I am doing I just got an error: Cannot read property 'comments' of undefined

Comment: @AgilYolchuyev I am not sure why you have so many ng-controllers or even controllers for single functions only

Comment: I changed javascript part.

Comment: @AgilYolchuyev See how its structured now

Comment: thank you so much for all your comments. I appreciate your help to me. I have done by the same way too. The problem is I still get an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'comments' of undefined
    at b.$scope.submitComment (app.js:169). My problem is that in view part (html code) I have live preview and in console.log it show me normal results. But I think the problem in push to array part and I don't know what is a reason.